# React-planner complies but produces no output

Tags: reactjs, toolchain

Description of how I arrived at the issue:  Whilst relatively new to react I have some years experience with Node.js, so I would expect to be able to get a library working.

Installation tripped a couple of times in the catalogue, one of the mtl files referenced a png when the file was a jpg - this was changed and seems successful.

And another file has

```
import ImageFul from './imageful';
```

which had to be changed to

```
import ImageFul from './imageful.jsx';
```

which I changed but does this mean that I am missing some part of the toolchain?

The main (Github) page does not mention any prerequisites in terms of libraries or loaders (I had to set up and configure `babel-plugin-import-glob`) what so I am asking myself what other npm dependencies are not installed with `react-planner`?

Anyway having gone through a painful process, the package finally compiled - but shows nothing and gives this set of errors in the Chrome console:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:6 [BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "http://planner.appl/js/dist/main.js" as it exceeds the max of "500KB".
r @ react_devtools_backend.js:6
i @ babel.min.js:10
t @ babel.min.js:10
t.default @ babel.min.js:10
n.generate @ babel.min.js:2
n.transform @ babel.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:14
n.wrap @ babel.min.js:2
e.transform @ babel.min.js:14
s @ babel.min.js:1
r @ babel.min.js:24
i @ babel.min.js:24
r @ babel.min.js:24
e.src.n..l.content @ babel.min.js:24
n.onreadystatechange @ babel.min.js:24
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
s @ babel.min.js:24
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:24
o @ babel.min.js:24
u @ babel.min.js:24
f @ babel.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:1
main.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: e.substr is not a function
at $a.load (:1:417556)
at ts.load (:1:418437)
at Module. (:45:1223858)
at n (:1:356)
at :1:1198
at :1:1210
at i (babel.min.js:24)
at r (babel.min.js:24)
at e.src.n..l.content (babel.min.js:24)
at XMLHttpRequest.n.onreadystatechange (babel.min.js:24)
load @ main.js:1
load @ main.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.js:53
n @ main.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
i @ babel.min.js:24
r @ babel.min.js:24
e.src.n..l.content @ babel.min.js:24
n.onreadystatechange @ babel.min.js:24
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
s @ babel.min.js:24
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:24
o @ babel.min.js:24
u @ babel.min.js:24
f @ babel.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ babel.min.js:1
[object%20Module]:1 GET {application url}[object%20Module] 404 (Not Found)
```

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: People are going to need more information. What did you do to setup the project? Maybe provide a link to the setup instructions you followed. Any configuration for web pack or something similar would probably be helpful.

Comment: From what I can tell, this is more or less a question for help debugging, which is really hard to do without any code to debug.

Comment: Fair points, however this is the planner page: https://github.com/cvdlab/react-planner , and this is the NPM page https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-planner may be I am missing something, but I cannot see any installation instructions.  Incidentally if I am missing something, just pointing me (so long as I get it going) is worth the bounty!

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/cvdlab/react-planner/blob/master/demo/webpack.config.js ?

Comment: Will do soon as back on main system - fingers crossed.

Comment: @x00 Sadly even the deom sticks with this error on a totally clean install:
`ERROR in ./src/renderer.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /xxx//node_modules/babel-preset-react/lib/index.js`
Have now spent several hours trying to use the hints from [https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6808]